# Can't ping host from docker container

Tags: networking, ip, gateway

my `/etc/network/interfaces` file when I am logged as the container looks like this

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.27
    netmask 255.255.255.240
    gateway 192.168.1.1
```

but when I do `ping 192.168.1.1` I get

```
connect: Network is unreachable
```

I don't understand why I cannot do that.

I get the same thing when pinging 8.8.8.8

Comment: A gateway must be on the same network as the host, otherwise you would need a gateway to reach the gateway. Your `192.168.1.1` gateway address is not in the `192.168.1.16/28` network of your `192.168.1.27/28` host address. A gateway is the host on a network that knows how to reach other networks, so having a gateway on a different network simply does not work.

Comment: so I have to modify the host to also register that network address? this is what I understood